# Helm Subchart order of execution in an umbrella chart

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-helm

I have an umbrella chart with multiple sub-charts, I simply want to make sure that subchart1 runs before subchart2, etc. How can we define the order of subchart execution?

Seems like hook-weights only apply relative to the chart that declares them.

Answer (score 26):

Here is a part of the Helm [documentation](https://helm.sh/docs/topics/charts/#operational-aspects-of-using-dependencies) related to execution order of charts:

> The above sections explain how to specify chart dependencies, but how
> does this affect chart installation using helm install and helm
> upgrade?
>
> Suppose that a chart named "A" creates the following Kubernetes
> objects
>
> namespace "A-Namespace" 
> statefulset "A-StatefulSet" 
> service "A-Service"

> Furthermore, A is dependent on chart B that creates
> objects
>
> namespace "B-Namespace" 
> replicaset "B-ReplicaSet" 
> service "B-Service"

> After installation/upgrade of chart A a single Helm release is
> created/modified. The release will create/update all of the above
> Kubernetes objects in the following order:
>
> A-Namespace 
> B-Namespace 
> A-StatefulSet 
> B-ReplicaSet 
> A-Service 
> B-Service

> This is because when Helm installs/upgrades charts, the Kubernetes
> objects from the charts and all its dependencies are aggregrated into a single set; then sorted by type followed by name;
> and then created/updated in that order. 
> Hence a single release is created with all the objects for the chart and its dependencies.
>
> The install order of Kubernetes types is given by the enumeration
> InstallOrder in kind_sorter.go ([Helm v2 source file](https://github.com/helm/helm/blob/9ad53aac42165a5fadc6c87be0dea6b115f93090/pkg/tiller/kind_sorter.go#L29)).

Part of kind_sorter.go ([Helm v3 source](https://github.com/helm/helm/blob/9b42702a4bced339ff424a78ad68dd6be6e1a80a/pkg/releaseutil/kind_sorter.go#L27)) is related to install charts:

```
var InstallOrder KindSortOrder = []string{
    "Namespace",
    "NetworkPolicy",
    "ResourceQuota",
    "LimitRange",
    "PodSecurityPolicy",
    "PodDisruptionBudget",
    "Secret",
    "ConfigMap",
    "StorageClass",
    "PersistentVolume",
    "PersistentVolumeClaim",
    "ServiceAccount",
    "CustomResourceDefinition",
    "ClusterRole",
    "ClusterRoleList",
    "ClusterRoleBinding",
    "ClusterRoleBindingList",
    "Role",
    "RoleList",
    "RoleBinding",
    "RoleBindingList",
    "Service",
    "DaemonSet",
    "Pod",
    "ReplicationController",
    "ReplicaSet",
    "Deployment",
    "HorizontalPodAutoscaler",
    "StatefulSet",
    "Job",
    "CronJob",
    "Ingress",
    "APIService",
}
```

There is a workaround, that can change the default behaviour, shared by **elementalvoid** in this [issue](https://github.com/kubernetes/helm/issues/1228):

> I've been setting my services, secrets, and configmaps as pre-install
> hooks to achieve this behavior.
>
> Example:
>
> ```
> apiVersion: v1
> kind: Service
> metadata:
>   name: foo
>   annotations:
>     "helm.sh/hook": "pre-install"
> ```

--

> It is possible to define a weight for a hook which will help build a
> deterministic executing order. Weights are defined using the following
> annotation:
>
> ```
>   annotations:
>     "helm.sh/hook-weight": "5"
> ```
>
> Hook weights can be positive or negative numbers but must be
> represented as strings. When Tiller starts the execution cycle of
> hooks of a **particular Kind** it will sort those hooks in ascending
> order.

More detailed information about hooks can be found here ([v2 doc](https://github.com/helm/helm/blob/9ad53aac42165a5fadc6c87be0dea6b115f93090/docs/charts_hooks.md#hooks), [v3 doc](https://helm.sh/docs/topics/charts_hooks/)) and in the source file ([helm v2 source](https://github.com/helm/helm/blob/9ad53aac42165a5fadc6c87be0dea6b115f93090/pkg/tiller/hooks.go), [helm v3 source](https://github.com/helm/helm/blob/02ad2b118731d012ea248e3ede800aa28fa71301/pkg/releaseutil/manifest_sorter.go#L54))

Comment: If i add a hook-weight configMap: 2 and Secret: 3, then this makes me think it will change the order of execution of resource type. But it does not, helm still enforces that order of secret -- configMap. Is it true, that If i have multiple configMaps with hook-weights, then hook-weights actually apply and sort the order for multiple confiMaps ?

Comment: You can't change order of types with hook-weights. May be developers change that in future, or add some additional parameter to achieve that, but now you are only able to change the order of multiple charts of the same type, like ConfigMaps.

Comment: The documentation link in the first line of the answer seems to be broken now. I found this link (https://helm.sh/docs/topics/charts/#operational-aspects-of-using-dependencies) with the same information.

Comment: Thanks! I've fixed the link.

Answer (score 8):

While you cannot make an order, you can use Init Containers to validate your Pods have everything they need to run before actually running them:
https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/pods/init-containers/

Answer (score 2):

You cannot make an order, and I don't think you will need it. You can rely on health checks, so if one chart depends on another, it will probably fail and restart until health check passes.