# Force pod creation order

Tags: kubernetes

Is there some way to force pod creation order on Kubernetes?

I have a scenario where Kubernetes are selecting a node pool with few resources and the first pod to be deployed consume a very small resource, but the next one consumes a lot of resources and the deployment fails.

So I was wondering if there is a way to instruct Kubernetes to deploy first the pod that is resource hog then the small ones

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [Node Selector](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/scheduling-eviction/assign-pod-node/#nodeselector) on your Pod’s specification, you just need [Node Labels](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/scheduling-eviction/assign-pod-node/#built-in-node-labels) for that.

Another option is to use [Node Affinity](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/configure-pod-container/assign-pods-nodes-using-node-affinity/). You just need to have the **Kubernetes cluster**, and the K8s command line ready (`kubectl`). The steps for that are:

- Add a label to the node.
- Schedule a Pod using required node affinity, or.
- Schedule a Pod using preferred node affinity.

Visit the official documentation I shared with you some lines above to have the detailed instructions, manifest examples, and the following URL for official K8’s documentation about [Assigning Pods to Nodes](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/scheduling-eviction/assign-pod-node/).

Plus, you can also set up the Pod initialization in a specific order. See this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56935239/how-to-configure-pod-initialization-in-a-specific-order-in-kubernetes) for the proper instructions.