# How can I control Install order of helm subcharts in an umbrella chart

Tags: kubernetes-helm

I have an umbrella chart containing multiple subcharts. I want to ensure that the subcharts are installed in a given order since some of them have dependencies on the others. Specifying them as hook resources can only control the order within the sub chart. Is there a way to control the order in such a way that the subcharts get installed in the specified order?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Helm Subchart order of execution in an umbrella chart](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50492389/helm-subchart-order-of-execution-in-an-umbrella-chart)

Comment: Usual Kubernetes practice is to start everything together; if something's dependencies aren't available yet (or have failed after startup) then the pod will crash and restart, but after a couple of minutes the whole stack will usually be up.  Helm doesn't have an option to order either subcharts or specific Kubernetes objects.

Answer (score 0):

Helm itself does not provide any tolling to control the installation order of the dependency charts. However, you can use any helm controller or CI/CD tool like [Flux](https://fluxcd.io/) to manage such dependency order.

Here, is an example of managing order of charts using Flux CD: https://fluxcd.io/docs/components/helm/helmreleases/#helmrelease-dependencies