# How to install istio mutating webhook and istiod first ahead of other pods in Helm?

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-helm, istio, kubeflow

I am trying to use Helm 3 to install Kubeflow 1.3 with Istio 1.9 on Kubernetes 1.16. Kubeflow does not provide official Helm chart so I figured it out by myself.

But Helm does not **guarantee** order. Pods of other deployments and statefulsets could be up before Istio mutating webhook and istiod are up. For example, if A pod is up earlier **without** istio-proxy, B pod is up later **with** a istio-proxy, they cannot communicate with each other.

Are there any simple best practices so I can work this out as expected each time I deploy? That is say, make sure my installation with Helm is **atomic**?

Thank you in advance.

UPDATE:
I tried for three ways:

1. mark resources as pre-install, post-install, etc.
2. using subcharts
3. decouple one chart into several charts

And I adopted the third. The issue of the first is that helm hook is designed for Job, a resource could be marked as helm hook but it would not be deleted when using `helm uninstall` since a resource cannot hold two helm hooks at the same time(key conflict in annotations). The issue of the second is that helm installs subcharts and charts at the same time, helm call hooks of subcharts and charts at the same time as well.

Comment: Which version of kubernetes did you use and how did you deploy it?

Comment: @MikołajGłodziak Kubernetes 1.16. I am trying to use subcharts to control order.

Answer (score 0):

> Helm does not **guarantee** order.

Not completely. Helm collects all of the resources in a given Chart and it's dependencies, groups them by resource type, and then installs them in the [following order](https://helm.sh/docs/intro/using_helm/#helm-install-installing-a-package):

> - Namespace
> - NetworkPolicy
> - ResourceQuota
> - LimitRange
> - PodSecurityPolicy
> - PodDisruptionBudget
> - ServiceAccount
> - Secret
> - SecretList
> - ConfigMap
> - StorageClass
> - PersistentVolume
> - PersistentVolumeClaim
> - CustomResourceDefinition
> - ClusterRole
> - ClusterRoleList
> - ClusterRoleBinding
> - ClusterRoleBindingList
> - Role
> - RoleList
> - RoleBinding
> - RoleBindingList
> - Service
> - DaemonSet
> - Pod
> - ReplicationController
> - ReplicaSet
> - Deployment
> - HorizontalPodAutoscaler
> - StatefulSet
> - Job
> - CronJob
> - Ingress
> - APIService

Additionally:

> That is say, make sure my installation with Helm is **atomic**

you should to know that:

> Helm does not wait until all of the resources are running before it exits.

You generally have no control over the order if you are using Helm. You can try to use Init Containers to validate your pods to check if they have all dependencies before they run. You can read more about it [here](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/pods/init-containers/). Another workaround will be to install a health check to make sure everything is okay. If not, it will restart until it is successful.

See also:

- this article about [checking your helm deployments](https://polarsquad.com/blog/check-your-helm-deployments).
- question [Helm Subchart order of execution in an umbrella chart](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50492389/helm-subchart-order-of-execution-in-an-umbrella-chart) with good explanation
- [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51957676/helm-install-in-certain-order)
- [related topic on github](https://github.com/helm/helm/issues/5723)